# Using asp.net in html pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

If I want to combine asp.net code with html (mark up) file, I need to open <% %> and execute teh code.

What If I want to iterate over a database with select query while feeding information and creating rows. For example:

```
<table>

<%
   foreach(DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["empoloyees"].Rows)
   {
%>
<tr>
<td>
      <asp:Label runat="Server" Text="<% dr[FirstName].toString(); %>"/>
</td>
<td>
      <asp:Label runat="Server" Text="<%dr[LastName].toString();%>"/>
</td>
</tr>
<%
   }
%>
</table>
```

Is the syntax correct..and is that practice good (it is always used in php) ? or should I bind the data to the label somehow?(no idea how. but somehow)?

Comment: You can't use `<%%>` inside the markup of a server side control.

Comment: this is so ASP classic old fashion approach, almost... as geekchic suggested use a repeater or Gridview and avoid this kind of mixing of markup and logic as ASP.NET has the advantage of separating markup from code-behind.

Comment: Looking at some of your comments, it seems you're maybe trying to avoid using ASP.NET controls, have you looked into ASP.NET MVC at all?

Comment: lol..I know VBscript..ahahaah.. MVC by what I saw is a whole different animal to webform design..Do I readlly need to learn MVC..I mean if i know webforms..why to make the conversion in desing..I also heard that MVC has got performance disadvantages..or other limits..I cant remember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and most important thing - do not mix business logic and data access functionality with the data representation markup!

Supposing you are using WebForms, you can use [Repeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which is bound in the code behind of a page/control (aspx.cs/ascx.cs) so View stay decoupled and just bound to specific properties of data source:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="employees" runat="server">   
<HeaderTemplate>   
<table> 
</HeaderTemplate>   
<ItemTemplate>   
<tr>   
<td>   
   <asp:Label runat="Server" 
              Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName") %>"/> 
</td> 
<td>        

   <asp:Label runat="Server" 
              Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName") %>"/> 
</td>   
</tr>   
</ItemTemplate>   
<FooterTemplate>   
</table>
</FooterTemplate>   
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code Behind: (Page_Load() for instance)**

```
employees.DataSource = dataset.Tables["empoloyees"].Rows;
employees.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to take a set of data and display it in a table then try using control like the  [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) or the [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx).

Comment: no thank you..dont trust thsoe 100%..I want to program freely from sql controls

Comment: @Matrix001 Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I am just not familiar with every control so much..and I also might want to be more flexible in my design than be limited to every tag that those controls have

Comment: @Matrix001 A repeater allows you to have full control over the output. They don't spit out any HTML without you specifically putting it in there. GridViews are very structured.

Comment: yeah, It reminds,,..the grid..the headache it caused me with all its tags

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) control if you want a piece of markup to iterate over and bind to it.

```
   <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName") %> </td>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName") %> </td>
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

Alternatively, use a [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx), though I find that `Repeater` gives you more control over the emitted markup.

Comment: I need to read more abou tthat Databinder..so are you saying that binding is best.. and not what I wrote?

Comment: @Matrix001 - Data binding is more idiomatic ASP.NET. You _can_ use `foreach` in the manner you have, but this is deemed more cluttered (mixing iteration logic with markup).

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Try this:

```
<table>

<%
   foreach(DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["empoloyees"].Rows)
   {
%>
<tr>
<td>
      <%= dr[FirstName].toString(); %>
</td>
<td>
      <%= dr[LastName].toString();%>
</td>
</tr>
<%
   }
%>
</table>
```

Comment: hmm..thanks for the syntax... <%= that means simply print on the screen..right? Do people use it by convention or not at all?!?!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a repeater instead something like this

```
 <table>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="userRepeater" >
        <ItemTemplate>
               <tr>
                  <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FirstName")%></td>
                  <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LastName")%></td>
               </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
 </table>
```

and in your codebehind

```
userRepeater.DataSource = dataset.Tables["empoloyees"];
userRepeater.DataBind();
```

for a list of all types of <% %> take a [look here](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use <% %> at all. Just put your code in between  tags with runat="server", and then go ahead and use standard ASP.NET tags (e.g. asp:TextBox runat="server"). Just make sure it's an *.aspx page.

FWIW, your question seems a little backwards to me. If you are creating *.aspx pages then you can just use standard HTML anywhere you want. If you are trying to somehow squish ASP.NET into an *.html page - then you are misunderstanding how ASP.NET works.

Comment: yeah, I know,,.I know it is not the classic asp.net. But assuming if I wanted to do that..could I ,,that way?